# Request for the correct spelling of "beautiful" and "wonderful"

Tags: лексикон, прилагательные, правописание

In my last holiday I met a lot of Russian people and they taught me a couple of Russian sentences, but only the pronunciation. Afterwards I tried to figure out how they are written, but I failed for two of those sentences.

Amongst others they taught me some compliments which means something like `You are very beautiful` and `You are a wonderful woman`. With help of a dictionary I could wrote down

> ты о́чень краси́вый.

but I guess that the inflexion is wrong. So, how is it spelled correctly? (It is, of course, directed towards a woman ;))

The other is a bit more complicated, I just can recreate:

> ты __ де́вушка.

If I write down the missing word as I understood the pronunciation the word is something along "obaldjennaja". What is the missing word and how is it spelled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ты о́чень краси́вый.

That targets a male person. Saying that may make you sound gay in certain circumstances.

To target a girl, you must say:

> ты о́чень краси́вая.

---

obaldjennaja -> `Обалденная`.

A girl that makes you [`обалдеть`](http://lingvo.yandex.ru/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/) (go out of one's mind, lose one's wits; become dulled/crazed; be stunned)

This is very colloquial and almost always means you want some sort of relationship with that girl (unless it's your sister or a female friend with which you already have this level of informality).

Comment: I think it's a very correct answer. I'd add that the originally suggested `You are a wonderful woman` would actually required the word `чудесная` in Russian, which would sound more gentle than `обалденная`. The latter is more suitable for a night club.